# On Veins, how to get some values from ini file?

Tags: omnet++, veins, simulationx

On **[Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/)** applications (`veins/src/modules/application/app_name.(cc, h`), how to get values like 
`*.car[*].appl.numVehicles` from the`ini` file?

I can get values like `sim-time-limit` (see below) and anothers createad by me one, by I can't acess values on `*.car[*].*` or `*.rsu[*].*` from ini file.

```
stringTmp = ev.getConfig()->getConfigValue("sim-time-limit");
```

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the "`numVehicles`" parameter from the .ini file using the following codification:

```
long numV = Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchdAccess().get()->par("numVehicles").longValue();
```

I hope this can help you.

Douglas

Comment: Cool!
I needed to add one include in my BaseWaveApplLayer.h and your code works.
`#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.h"`

Now I can get all value from [TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.ned](https://github.com/namnatulco/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.ned) using the [TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchdAccess](https://github.com/namnatulco/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.h#L64).get().
Thank you for all the help : ).

Answer (score 1):

Reading parameter values of a module can be done via a call to this module's `par(...)` method.

I would highly recommend doing the TicToc tutorial, where this is demonstrated succinctly

Comment: Hello Sommer. I have read the TicToc tutorial. I'm using `par(...)`, but I can't get values from somes module. For exemple, I want get the value of  `*.manager.numVehicles` (from veins/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.ned), I tried with `par(...)`, but he don't accept . or *, so I created one variable `numVehicles` (to use `*.car[*].appl.numVehicles`) on  BaseWaveApplLayer.ned to get this value and I have to make sure that with both have the same value. Maybe has one way with `par(...)` to get this value directly, but I don't know how. Thanks for your help until now : ).